Mapstruct use another mapper with multiple parameters and lombok @Builder
I want to use Mapstruct to build a target object with a nested object inside, from two sources objects and using Lombok alongside. The description of the mapping is:
Target:
@Builder
class Kpi {
 String name;
 KpiMeta meta;
}

To build this class, I use two source objects: JmsMessageKpiDto and KpiDto.
I have defined a first Mapper which takes the same two source objects and create a KpiMeta target, and then I've created a second mapper which declares to use the first mapper to build the final Kpi object:
@Mapper(uses = KpiMetaMapper.class)
interface KpiMapper {
 KpiMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(KpiMapper.class);

 Kpi toKpi(JmsMessageKpiDto jms, KpiDto dto);
}

And for both of my target objects (Kpi and KpiMeta), I want to use @Builder from Lombok. But in the end, in the generated code the field KpiMeta is not populated inside the Kpi object.
Is there any solution to have this working?
Edit - solution
I decided to use @AfterMapping to achieve this mapping as I could not find a better solution
